# Docker compose + Nginx + PHP with Xdebug listen not working

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, nginx, xdebug

I am trying to debug my Laravel project on my Linux Ubuntu OS, so I configured Xdebug but its breakpoints do not listen to incoming requests.

- I am running in a Docker environment using Docker Compose.
- The Xdebug version is v3.2.2
- The IDE I use is VSCode.

When I run `phpinfo();` the Xdebug is enabled correctly but it does not work when I listen from within my VSCode IDE.

Here is my Docker compose file

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - .docker/php/conf.d/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
      - .docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
      - .docker/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    mem_limit: 1024m
    mem_reservation: 512M
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

  server:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: server
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 4.4.4.4
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - .docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network
```

The app (php) Dockerfile content:

```
FROM php:8.1.18-fpm
WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip sendmail libpng-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        default-mysql-client \
        net-tools \
        inetutils-ping \
        netcat \
        && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
        && docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y zip libzip-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install exif && docker-php-ext-enable exif

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl

RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Regarding the nginx config

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;

    index index.php index.html;
    
    root /var/www/html/public;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        # Enable CORS Preflighted requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';

            return 204;
        }

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        gzip_static on;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

And here is the xdebug.ini config content:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode = debug,develop
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE ; can also be phpstorm

;; ------------------------------------
;; Color var_dumps when in CLI
xdebug.cli_color=1
```

This is the `launch.json` file content for Xdebug within my VSCode:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is example image of my `phpinfo()`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to expose the xdebug port in your docker-compose.yml. There are a lot pre-defined docker-images already providing you everything you need to run php + xdebug. Try them out and take a look a their configuration, e.g. https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-apache-dev.html

Comment: @Roman Thanks a lot which port you think should be exposed `9000` or `9003`, the thing is that I did not find a tutorial do expose a port for xdebug, that is the reason I did not do it in my docker compose file

Comment: You can check my solution too, maybe you will find what is missing in yours: https://github.com/Fresh-Advance/development and looks like i dont have those ports exposed at all, i just use specific xdebug configuration to connect back https://github.com/Fresh-Advance/development/blob/master/containers/php-fpm/xdebug.ini

Comment: You do NOT need to expose Xdebug port. Simply because it's Xdebug that connects to VSCode and NOT other way around. If you expose the port then Docker is using it and VSCode will be unable to listen for incoming Xdebug connections. RTM please.